# addPrefencesFromResource causes ClassCastException

Tags: java, android, preferences, classcastexception

**Code:**

```
public class Preferences extends PreferenceActivity {
public static final String PREF_AUTO_UPDATE = "PREF_AUTO_UPDATE";
public static final String PREF_MIN_MAG = "PREF_MIN_MAG";
public static final String PREF_UPDATE_FREQ = "PREF_UPDATE_FREQ";

SharedPreferences prefs;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Context context = getApplicationContext();

    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.userprefs);


}
```

Every time I switch over to the preferences activity, I get a run time error that crashes my app.  Down the trace I get:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer

After doing some debugging I found that commenting out the line `addPreferencesFromResource` will keep the app from crashing, but (obviously) doesn't load any UI.  I'm copying this example pretty much line for line out of a text book and can't figure out for the life of me what I am missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was playing with this stuff and hit kind of the same thing.  Turns out I was doing a putInt but then the xml file defining the preferences had a TextEditPreference hooked up with the relevant key.  As far as I can tell, TextEditPreference insists on interacting with the sharedpreferences file via putString/getString (duh), and the putInt I did somewhere in playing around had stuck an  element in the app-preferences.xml (/data/data/../shared_prefs/..), which kills the preference activity every time it calls addPreferencesFromResource.  Not sure if that's what going on in your case, but I think folks can help once you post your userprefs and also note if you are using putInt on the TextEditPreference's key yourself in code or anything like I was (incorrectly) doing.

Answer (score 0):

Check your resources type. That could be the problem.

Comment: could you elaborate a little more?  userprefs.xml is an xml file with the path res/xml/userprefs.

Comment: It seems to me that there's a situation when your try to supply String resource to int value or smth. Could you post your userprefs.xml?